# cucumber feature file to run in order

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, cucumber-java

Problem: I need to run my cucumber .feature file to execute in an order defined by me and rather not to run in the default order which is the folder structure.

I am running Appium for Android Native Apps built using cucumber .features file.
on windows machine, running on actual devices.

Now my Runcuckes file looks like below:

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
 import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
 import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

 //@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

 @CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/java/features" }, 
             glue = { "Steps" }, 
             monochrome = true, 
             tags = {  "@CustomerInsightsSurveyPopupGiveFeedback,"
                     + "@TestAccountSceanrios"
                     + "@ShortlistPage,"
                     + "@SavedSearchesPage,"
                     + "@SearchResultPage,"
                     + "@Short,"
                     + "@SuggestedSearch" })

        // public class RunCucke {
         public class RunCucke extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your features or scenarios in order is Cuking the WRONG way.

In all testing linking one test to another is an anti-pattern. It makes your tests fragile and difficult to debug. Each test should be independent of every other test.

In Cucumber you use Givens to setup the state of your scenario. When's to actually do something. Then's to check your results. Your scenarios Given's should include everything needed to setup your application so you can do your When.

Cucumber encourages you to run your scenarios in a random order, and to reset just about everything between each scenario. Don't work against this, you will make things much more difficult if you do.

Comment: This may be true for small tests. But when we do a journeys and composite journeys there is a dependency exists. It is highly difficult to put all together in one feature file. in this case any alternative way to use? Defining order for group of tests is my requirement. Using tags doesn't solve the problem. Only way is multiple runs for each group and naming sequence of feature files with in a group. But this doesn't look clean and good. There should be a way to extend the cucumber runtime and provide a  configuration file will help us.

Comment: No Mujibur this is true for all tests at all scales. Any process no matter how complex can be expressed in a simple form. In the same way any simple thing can be expressed as numerous smaller components. The power Cucumber encourages you to use is to express things using higher abstractions e.g. `When I build a car` rather than `When I assemble the wheels, brakes, engine ...`. What you need to do is change the way you are thinking about your problems rather than trying to change Cucumber.